# App Crashes when ReloadData done for the tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I am using the following code to reload my tableView when its done adding all the data to my Mutable Arrays, but the app always crashes

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Spinner Add while waiting
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(147, 10, 25, 25);
    [self.tableView addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    usersFirstName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    usersLastName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    usersAvatar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.test.com/scribble/%@/",scribbleId];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
        users = JSON[@"users_favored"];
        if (users.count > 0) {
            NSUInteger count = [users count];
            for (NSUInteger i =0; i<count; i++) {
                NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.test.com%@",[users objectAtIndex:i]];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                NSURLRequest *requestUser = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:requestUser success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                    if (i == 0) {
                        usersFirstName = [JSON[@"first_name"] mutableCopy];
                        usersLastName = [JSON[@"last_name"] mutableCopy];
                        usersAvatar = [JSON[@"user_avatar"] mutableCopy];
                    }else{
                        [usersFirstName addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"first_name"]];
                        [usersLastName addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"last_name"]];
                        [usersAvatar addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"user_avatar"]];
                    }
                    if (i == count-1) {
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                        [spinner stopAnimating];
                        [spinner removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                }failure:nil];
                [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
            }
        }else{
            self.navigationItem.title = @"No Favors";
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            [spinner removeFromSuperview];
        }
    } failure:nil];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return usersFirstName.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableFavorIdentifier = @"FavorCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableFavorIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableFavorIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *firstName = [usersFirstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *lastName = [usersLastName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *avatar = [usersAvatar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *userFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
    UIImageView *userAvatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    if ([avatar length ] > 0) {
        NSString *img = [@"https://dtest_media_and_assets.s3.amazonaws.com/" stringByAppendingString:avatar];
        [userAvatar setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scribble.png"]];
    }else{
        userAvatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scribble.png"];
    }
    userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    userAvatar.clipsToBounds = YES;
    UILabel *userNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    userNameLabel.text = userFullName;

    return cell;

}
```

The error it gives is

```
 2013-03-15 16:37:08.910 test[19547:c07] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8679c80

2013-03-15 16:37:08.911 test[19547:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8679c80'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cdf012 0x169fe7e 0x1d6a4bd 0x1ccebbc 0x1cce94e 0x143d7 0x7c8548 0x7cb224 0x68f952 0x68f2dc 0x140d7 0x281d2 0x29569 0x2f9553f 0x2fa7014 0x2f977d5 0x1c85af5 0x1c84f44 0x1c84e1b 0x21bb7e3 0x21bb668 0x5e3ffc 0x200d 0x1f35)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

## Edit

everything works just fine when I use this instead

```
[usersFirstName addObject:JSON[@"first_name"]];
[usersLastName addObject:JSON[@"last_name"]];
[usersAvatar addObject:JSON[@"user_avatar"]];
[self.tableView reloadData];
if (i == count-1) {
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: None of the code you posted is related to the error. Where do you call a `count` method or access a `count` property?

Comment: Actually, perhaps the problem is that your JSON results are really returning a single string value where you assume there is an array.

Comment: Please post a symbolic stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe please have a look at the edit

Comment: @rmaddy it gives me the same error when I use addObject instead of addObjectsFromArray, also please have a look at the edit

Comment: No, what @rmaddy is saying is that error is caused by calling `[NSString count]` (a method which doesn't exist).  Your code doesn't do that, so it's probably not in the code you show.  Also those numbers are meaningless to anyone; we need to see the method names in the stacktrace (use `bt` from the debugging console).

Comment: btw you should use the dot notation only for accessing properties, not for calling functions. since count is not a property but a function you should write `[usersFirstName count]` instead of `usersFirstName.count`.

Comment: @Bastian even then it gives the same error

Comment: yeah .. that was more a cosmetic hint... did you try to step through the function using breakpoints and the debugger to check where exactly the crash happens ?

Comment: @Bastian yes. it happens on the reload

Comment: @Jonathan If its fixed,please accept the answer of Bastian. BTW why are you keeping an array each for username, lastname, avatar image etc. A model class for user will make your work a lot easier.

Comment: @Anupdas yes I have fixed my Model class now. I ended up dissecting it that is why it was separate. I was trying to fix my code. and What Bastain suggested. I was using that before as well, but is that the best approach?

Comment: @Jonathan That is the best approach to work with data model objects. You can even put routine validations there. As you keep on adding features this approach will keep your code clean and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the same with that function:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"usersFirstName is of type %@", NSStringFromClass([usersFirstName class]));
    return [usersFirstName count]; 
}
```

---

I guess you have to replace:

```
          if (i == 0) {
                    usersFirstName = [JSON[@"first_name"] mutableCopy];
                    usersLastName = [JSON[@"last_name"] mutableCopy];
                    usersAvatar = [JSON[@"user_avatar"] mutableCopy];
                }else{
                    [usersFirstName addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"first_name"]];
                    [usersLastName addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"last_name"]];
                    [usersAvatar addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"user_avatar"]];
                }
```

with just:

```
                    [usersFirstName addObject:JSON[@"first_name"]];
                    [usersLastName addObject:JSON[@"last_name"]];
                    [usersAvatar addObject:JSON[@"user_avatar"]];
```

Comment: So this is strange,

`2013-03-15 16:59:12.523 WorkSquid[73966:c07] usersFirstName is of type __NSArrayM
2013-03-15 16:59:12.789 WorkSquid[73966:c07] usersFirstName is of type __NSCFString`

I think the former comes from before the reload, and latter after it reloads

Comment: is `usersLastName = [JSON[@"last_name"] mutableCopy];` setting an string to the variable ?

Comment: so you are replacing the array with a string.

Comment: thats what I have been using, but then it doesnt make this into a mutable array, but makes a new one every time

Comment: this is in the viewdidload function... it should be only called one time for the lifetime of the view.. what everytime do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that this:

```
users = JSON[@"users_favored"];
```

Returns an `NSString`, when it looks you are expecting an `NSArray`.

Verify this using:

```
users = JSON[@"users_favored"];
NSLog(@"users is of type %@", NSStringFromClass([users class]));
```

Something is either wrong with your assumption or the JSON is broken.

Comment: It says that users is of type __NSCFArray

Comment: @Jonathan That is surprising.  I'm out.